# Why is there a red squiggle in my c++ code (both in VS and in VScode) even tho it compiles?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I reduced the problem to this small working code:

```
#include<iostream>

int main() {
    std::string s = "1";
    int i = stoi(s);
    return 0;
}
```

This code compiles without errors in VSCode with wsl linux, but **stoi is underlined with red**.

If I add

```
#include <string>
```

, then everything is good. But my school assignment doesn't allow to add any includes to the code.

The above code **in Visual Studio doesn't compile at all**, and the suggested quick fix is to use the string library, which, again, I am not allowed to use.

Apart from searching the internet endlessly, I tried the following:

1. I suspected my compiler is not updated, so I updated g++ in wsl.

   Now *g++ --version* in WSL returns:

> g++ (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0 Copyright (C) 2019 Free
> Software Foundation, Inc. This is free software; see the source for
> copying conditions.  There is NO warranty; not even for
> MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

2. I reset Visual Studio 2017 to its default settings.
3. I updated Visual Studio 2017 to 2019.
4. I updated Microsoft Visual C++.
5. When I tried g++ --version in command prompt on Windows, it said g++ is not recognized as a command, so I downloaded MinGW and installed the compilers.

   Now *g++ --version* in Windows 10 returns:

> g++ (MinGW.org GCC Build-2) 9.2.0 Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software
> Foundation, Inc. This is free software; see the source for copying
> conditions.  There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or
> FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Does anybody know why my code doesn't compile in Visual Studio 2019 and why there is a red squiggle in VSCode? By the way I have the same issue with the getline() function, I suspect the same cause behind it.

Comment: `std::stoi` is defined in include `<string>`.  If you are not allowed to `#include <string>` it should probably be presumed that you are not allowed to use `std::stoi`.  Perhaps you are being tested whether you can implement what `std::stoi` does.

Comment: "Why is there a red squiggle in my c++ code (both in VS and in VScode) even tho it compiles?" - because your IDE is *not* the compiler and it often gets things wrong when trying to provide helpful hints quickly.

Comment: *This code compiles without errors in VSCode* -- VSCode is not a compiler -- more than likely the compiler is `g++` -- you need to be aware of the tools you are using to build your application, and the actual compiler must be one of those tools that you have to be aware of.   Also, there is no guarantee that the code will compile successfully if you do not `#include <string>`. -- *I updated Microsoft Visual C++.* -- There is nothing to update -- you thought that the code will compile if you are missing that `#include <string>`, and that was a wrong assumption.

Comment: @DrewDormann the stoi() function is in the part of the code that I am not allowed to change.

Comment: All the things you are having trouble with (`stoi` and `getline`) are declared in the `<string>` header which for some reason you are not allowed to use. So, don't try and use them.

Comment: @GergelyBertalan Then you have been given code which is invalid. Makes me wonder about the quality of the teacher. `stoi` is declared in the `<string>` header file which you must include before trying to use it.

Comment: Because of **argument-dependent lookup** (ADL), the `stoi` function is found in the `std` namespace.  However, the code is relying on an *indirect include* (via `#include <iostream>`, which is not reliable.  (Doesn't compile on my machine because of the missing include.)

Comment: If you were given code that requires `#include <string>` but doesn't and you are not allowed to add it yourself, then I'd say that your teaching material is bollocks and/or your teacher is incompetent.

Comment: @GergelyBertalan -- You *must* `#include <string>` if you are going to use `std::string` in any way -- there is no ifs or buts about it.  It doesn't matter if you are using `std::stoi` or not.  Just declaring a `std::string` requires that header for successful compilation across compilers.

Comment: @Eljay You sure ADL is the reason?  The OP shouldn't even be able to declare a `std::string`.  That they can implies `<iostream>` includes `<string>`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie yes, I used g++ to compile in WSL. So when I compile with g++ in VSCode using WSL, it works, while VSCode gives red squiggles. If the IDE got it wrong with the hints as Jesper Juhl said, then shouldn't it also compile on windows with Visual Studio? Or is the compiler set wrong in VS?

Comment: @GergelyBertalan "red squiggles" are often _red herrings_ in Microsoft development products.  They should not be interpreted as any factual indication that something is wrong with your code.  They are suggestions and they are sometimes bad suggestions.  You must fix _compiler error messages_, but a red squiggle can sometimes be safely ignored.

Comment: @GergelyBertalan - Stop looking at red squiggles.  The code is not guaranteed to compile unless you specify `#include <string>`.

Comment: @GergelyBertalan Also, please look at the documentation for [std::stoi](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol).  Note that the documentation states `Defined in header <string>`.  Thus you must `#include` that header to guarantee compilation, instead of using just `<iostream>` and getting lucky that `g++` just by coincidence includes `<string>`.

Comment: Thanks everyone, you guys were right. About the quality of the teacher: We had many many more issues with the quality of her course, which course - as promised by the board - will be taught by someone else from next year.